# Backflow preventer spewing water

Tags: irrigation, backflow-preventer

I have a lf009mq2t watts backflow preventer which starts spewing water from its center nozzle anytime any of my three irrigation lines stops running (or if I run a hose while its valve is off). I can make it stop spewing by running any water in the house for a few seconds until what looks like some white air is pushed out. It used to work perfectly for four years since installation. What can I do?

[image: backflow preventer label]

[image: the location on the preventer where the water leaks]

[A video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9iif.jpg) of water flowing in the kitchen sink to stop the spewing water. (Also, full size images.)

Comment: Your backflow preventer is a Reduced Pressure Principle (RPP) (sometimes called RPZ for Reduced Pressure Zone) unit, and these are required to be tested by a plumber or other qualified serviceperson on a periodic basis -- have you tried contacting whoever does the tests on it for service?

Comment: Also, I take it the backflow preventer spews continuously until you run water in the house, and the house water is tapped off upstream of the backflow preventer?

Answer (score 1):

### Your RPZ needs servicing

That sort of continuous spitting or streaming from a Reduced Pressure Principle/Zone (RPP or RPZ) assembly with nothing going on downstream is a sign that the assembly needs to be serviced.  In particular, Watts' own troubleshooting guidance [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3XMAitov6s) on the topic says that if the relief port is spitting, dripping, or streaming continuously in a no-downstream-flow condition, one should close the downstream valve on the assembly, then open the most-downstream (#4) test cock with a standard screwdriver to relieve pressure on the chamber.  If the flow from the relief valve drain stops, then that's a sign the first check is fouled or sticking; if it continues, then the relief valve itself is not seating.

Either way, you'll need to either get a rebuild kit and service the RPZ yourself with it following the instructions in the video or [installation manual](http://media.wattswater.com/1911300.pdf), or have a plumber or irrigation technician qualified as a backflow preventer tester fix it for you.  Some local codes may require that a qualified tester perform the repair, even, and will also require in that case that the unit be tested regularly by said qualified tester.

P.S. if you haven't a clue about finding someone who's qualified to work on backflow assemblies and don't feel comfortable DIYing this, *call your water utility*!  They'll be able to get you a list of referrals at minimum, and may even be willing to send a technician out to test it themselves, depending on utility policies.